# What is the use of 1k resistor shown in the picture and why it is used? Please check Arduino Uno Schematics for more info

Tags: arduino-uno

[image: Arduino Uno Schematics]

Can anyone tell me why 1k resistor is used on pin 13 of ATmega16U2 in arduino uno schematics. I have also seen a 100k resistor used in this position?

Link for schematics - https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Uno_Rev3-schematic.pdf

Comment: You musrt be kidding! You present part of a schematic whose only completely shown component is one single resistor and you ask about its purpose!

Comment: What's the use?!!

Comment: @curd you can check arduino uno schematic for more detail on this. I particularly wanted to know about it so i cropped it out.

Comment: @Andyaka I am just curious how this works.

Comment: @Gahlot: this information belongs into the text of the question.

Comment: @curd updated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a pulldown resistor!

Comment there says "USB Boot Enable" so safe assumption that it's an digital pin.

They're handy because they mean if there is no input to whether that pin is headed, the voltage at the pin will be 0 instead of floating.

The value doesn't matter too much, "When in doubt 10k it out" is a pretty well known saying around electronics people, meaning just use a 10k Ohm resistor and you'll be fine.

Comment: How do you know?!?! It's connected to an input that can be an analog input. Therefore the resistor could just as well be the lower part of a voltage divider, it could be part of a RC filter, or anything else...

Comment: @Curd based on the fact its got a label for USB Boot Enable, sounds digital to me

Comment: it is a digital pin only.

Comment: @Timmy Hadwen: that's likely but without further context just an assumtion.

Comment: @Gahlot: why didn't you tell that in the question?!? and still then you should tell, or better, show more about the signal at that line.

Comment: I will keep that in mind from next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Pin 13 of the USB interface chip is connected to RESET line of the ATMEGA328 MCU. I would guess (also from "USB boot En" label) that pressing/issuing board reset gives the USB interface an interrupt (INT7), such that USB bootloader gets activated and the ATMEGA328 can start loading firmware code over USB. The resistor is a pull-down resistor ensuring LOW signal, and its value shouldn't matter much. However, there is a capacitor (C5) which provides a short pulse to the interrupt line. This is not the best way to form a digital signal and initiate an interrupt, but the RC should be long enough, so I would expect that if 100k is used, the cap can be much smaller than 100n as in 1k case.

Comment: i have seen a 100k resistor connected in pull up configuration though that's another topic. Can you explain your answer in more detail?